# CMake pkg-config Mode: Version

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, pkg-config

I am trying to use the CMake `--find-package` mode to verify in a one-liner if a usable version of boost exists.

This can generally be done via

```
cmake --find-package -DNAME=Boost -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=CXX -DMODE=EXIST
```

but I would like to know the if a *minimal version* was found.

For example in a CMakeList.txt this would read

```
find_package(Boost 1.60.0)
```

I tried to encode it in the -DNAME, searched the web for the problem and tried to guess a variable like -DMINVERSION but could not find a solution or [documentation entry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindPackageMode.html) that describes further options.

A current work-around I am using looks like this

```
echo -e "#include <boost/version.hpp>\n#include <iostream>\n" \
        "int main() { std::cout << BOOST_VERSION << std::endl; return 0; }" \
    | g++ -I$BOOST_ROOT/include -x c++ - || { echo 0; }
BOOST_FOUND=$([ $(./a.out) -ge 106000 ] && { echo 0; } || { echo 1; })
```

Comment: [Current implementation](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeFindPackageMode.cmake#L190) just calls `find_package("${NAME}" QUIET)`. It looks like one cannot search package with specific version using this mechanism (`cmake --find-package`).

Comment: Great catch, looks like providing a patch would be very straight forward to add this functionality.